# Only include outliers from each column in a dataframe

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
 chr   leftPos         TBGGT     12_try      324Gtt       AMN2
  1     24352           34         43          19         43
  1     53534           2          1           -1         -9
  2      34            -15         7           -9         -18
  3     3443           -100        -4          4          -9
  3     3445           -100        -1          6          -1
  3     3667            5          -5          9           5
  3     7882           -8          -9          1           3
```

I have to create a loop which:

a) Calculates the upper and lower limit (UL and LL) for each column from the third column onwards.
b) Only includes rows that fall *outside* of the UL and LL (Zoutliers).
c) Then count the number of rows where the Zoutlier is the same direction (i.e. positive or negative) as the previous *or* the subsequent row *for the same chr*.

The output would therefore be:

```
 ZScore1    TBGGT     12_try      324Gtt       AMN2
 nrow        4         6            4           4
```

So far I have code as follows:

```
  library(data.table)#v1.9.5
  f1 <- function(df, ZCol){

  #A) Determine the UL and LL and then generate the Zoutliers
  UL = median(ZCol, na.rm = TRUE) + alpha*IQR(ZCol, na.rm = TRUE)
  LL = median(ZCol, na.rm = TRUE) - alpha*IQR(ZCol, na.rm = TRUE)
  Zoutliers <- which(ZCol > UL | ZCol < LL)

  #B) Exclude Zoutliers per chr if same direction as previous or subsequent row
  na.omit(as.data.table(df)[, {tmp = sign(eval(as.name(ZCol)))
  .SD[tmp==shift(tmp) | tmp==shift(tmp, type='lead')]},
  by=chr])[, list(.N)]}

  nm1 <- paste0(names(df)
  setnames(do.call(cbind,lapply(nm1, function(x) f1(df, x))), nm1)[]
```

The code is patched together from various places. The problem I have is combining parts A) and B) of the code to get the output I want

Comment: Is `Zcol` supposed to be essentially `3:ncol(df)` , i.e. all columns from number 3 onward, or just one column at a time?

Comment: It should calculate it one column at a time. I guess the output of the first part of the code should give me all the Z outliers with the chr and leftPos they are in which I think it does. The second part should then take that column and for each chr then assess each row as described. That's the idea. So should I pass Zoutliers to the second part?

Comment: If I just concentrate on the first part- how would I get the Zoutliers with chr and leftPos associated which I could then pass to the second part of the problem

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this function? I was not sure what `alpha` is, so I could not reproduce the expected output and included it as variable in the function.

```
# read your data per copy&paste
d <- read.table("clipboard",header = T)
# or as in Frank comment mentioned solution via fread
d <- data.table::fread("chr   leftPos         TBGGT     12_try      324Gtt       AMN2
                                     1     24352           34         43          19         43
                                     1     53534           2          1           -1         -9
                                     2      34            -15         7           -9         -18
                                     3     3443           -100        -4          4          -9
                                     3     3445           -100        -1          6          -1
                                     3     3667            5          -5          9           5
                                     3     7882           -8          -9          1           3")


# set up the function
foo <- function(x, alpha, chr){
  # your code for task a) and b)
  UL = median(x, na.rm = TRUE) + alpha*IQR(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  LL = median(x, na.rm = TRUE) - alpha*IQR(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  Zoutliers <- which(x > UL | x < LL)
  # part (c
  # factor which specifies the direction. 0 values are set as positives
  pos_neg <- ifelse(x[Zoutliers] >= 0, "positive", "negative")
  # count the occurrence per chromosome and direction.
  aggregate(x[Zoutliers], list(chr[Zoutliers], pos_neg), length)
}

# apply over the columns and get a list of dataframes with number of outliers per chr and direction.
apply(d[,3:ncol(d)], 2, foo, 0.95, d$chr)
```

Comment: Fyi, the package now offers the `fread` function which you can use to read in text like `DT= fread("text text text")`

Comment: @Frank Oh, good to know. Included this function in my answer.